# Set project root?

Tags: c++, compilation, include

How can I setup my project root so that, when I include my files I want it to search for, the file will start from the root, similarly to Java. Example dir:

```
-project root
--main.cpp
--dir
---foo.h
---foo.cpp
--dir2
---boo.h
---boo.cpp
```

From `foo.h`, I want to be able to write `#include "dir2/boo.h"`. I do not want to use `../`. Should I use some sort of compilation flags? I am not using an IDE, I am on a Mac and I am currently using the g++ compiler.

Comment: This is a question about your compiler/toolchain, not about the C++ language. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: updated complier

Comment: You told us you're using GCC, but what version? I'm trying to train you to provide all pertinent details. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you'd achieve this by adding an *include path* into your compilation command.

For GCC, this is `-I<path>` (e.g. `g++ myCode.cpp -I"project root" -o executable`).

In all cases, read your compiler's *documentation*, which lots of people lovingly spent hours and hours writing just for you to find this sort of information without having to ask about it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. For some reason I could not find this through google.

Comment: @stas: Googling things is not proper research. When you use a tool (e.g. `g++`) you should read through its documentation. You will not be able to just Google everything you need as you will not know the search terms to look for. Reading through the documentation will imbue you with knowledge and understanding. Yes, this takes time. Get used to it!